# AndroidStudio: редактор не понимает формат файла

Tags: android-studio

Что-то сделал, что именно не помню, но теперь все файлы имеющие имя activity_main.xml воспринимаются как обычный текст (видимо это имя добавилось в список неких исключений). Как сделать чтобы этот файл опять воспринимался разметкой???[image: введите сюда описание изображения]